# Excel Custom Time Format Decode in PHP

Tags: php, excel, timestamp

I've got ton of spreadsheets I'm processing in PHP and one of the cells contain a timestamp which has a custom formatting of: `[h]:mm:ss.0;@`

This turns a number such as 2.09491E-05 into 0:00:01.8

When I read it into php I can only get the value of 2.09491E-05 but I don't know how to convert this into seconds. Can anyone help?

Comment: Quick calculation shows that `86400` seconds in a day * `2.09491e-5` = `1.8` seconds, which equals `0:00:01.8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, one day equates to 1. So in order to convert the Excel representation of 1.81 seconds, 2.09491E-05, into a number where each second equals 1, just multiply by the number of seconds in a day, i.e., 24*60*60, or 86,400:

```
2.09491E-05 * 86,400 = 1.81
```